# When I type in A Loop Command on Python it doesn't follow the statement?

Tags: loops

So basically this is my homework for school we've been programming a small Quiz on Python Using Idle I have tried adding a loop to Rerty the quiz if you didn't do well but when you type in 0 For it to turn off the app closes like it should do but when I Put 1 for To Rerty it Reapeats the same command over and over again and doesn't restart the quiz. Here is The Script.

[image: the screenshot of the Script]

Comment: Make your question more readable. For example add more punctuation marks..

Answer (score 1):

Right now you only have the script loop over the part where it asks them if they want to try again, it has no way to control the flow back up to the beginning and ask all the questions.

Consider changing the flow with a function definition

```
def quiz():
    # code that asks questions goes here 
    # show them their score ask if they want to go again
    if yes:
       quiz() # restart the function within itself (recursion) 
    else:
       print ("okay bye") 

quiz() # this is the first call that gets it all started
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop starts over where the `while` statement is. Right now it doesn't repeat the quiz because the program does the quiz, then gets trapped between quitting

```
   answer.lower().startswith("0") 
   exit()
```

and just repeating the loop, which again only gives the options to quit or repeat the loop. It repeats the loop because you're telling it to print `ok, carry on then` and then start back at `while`

You can place the quiz itself inside the `while` loop so the quiz gets run every time the `while` loop restarts.

```
while True:
   QUIZ
   quit = input('Retry or quit?')
   if quit:
      exit()
   elif not quit
       whatever you want to say here, the program won't exit so it starts back at the while
```